# Posting without button click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql-server, webmatrix-2

Ok, I am building a site with MS Webmatrix and ASP.net, c#, javascript.
I want to have my clients enter info, then if I can verify it on my database, go to paypal for payment. So the flow would be

1. client enters info
2. validate against the db
3. go to PayPal for payment.

So I really don't want a *pay now* button to go directly to paypal. I can easily route the *pay now* to html that verifies and if failed, displays appropriate msgs and prompts.

If the info verifies, how can I route to PayPal without the user clicking another button?
Is there code that I can put in my script to send to paypal without clicking or programmatically force the click without client intervention?

Also, I would like the ability to recall the clients billing address in the future if a refund is requested so I can mail a check. I prefer to manually mail a check. Can I capture/store a PayPal transaction id, then use the transaction id to request the billing address months later (if needed) so I don't have to store the address in my database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to make an HTTP request to PayPal and to manage its response.

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect server sided ? Just use the Web Classes then.

About PayPal: There is a SOAP/XML API, there you can do such stuff like TransactionSearch. Just check https://developer.paypal.com/ or check this: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/PP_API_Reference.pdf

Comment: Am I close with the following code?

public class Test
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException ("Specify the URI of the resource to retrieve.");
        }
        WebClient client = new WebClient ();
        client.BaseAddress = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        client.Headers.Add("hosted_button_id","abcdefg1234");

        Stream data = client.OpenRead ("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");

Comment: StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        Console.WriteLine (s);
        data.Close ();
        reader.Close ();
    }
}

Comment: Update your question with the code to make it readable and add your expirience and/or problem what still not work.